# Call method on Apache CXF initialiaze

Tags: java, apache, cxf

I'm in the "how-to" phase with `Apache CXF` and would like to know if there's a way to call a method when the server is started.

It would be similar to a `JSF` web application, when I use a `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean with `eager=true`: when the container is started, the annotated class is instantiated and I can call whatever I want from its constructor.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, If you are using `CXF Servlet` to serve `Web Service` request, then you can create `ServletContextListener` and `contextInitialized` method will be called on deployment or on server start up if the application is already deployed.

To do that create class which will implement `ServletContextListener`:

```
public class YourContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {      
        //This method is called by the container on start up
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {        
    }   

}
```

Then define that listener in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>your.package.YourContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In the `contextInitialized` method you can get servlet context by using:

```
ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
```

And you can set as many attributes as you want to be available into whole application scope.